# Next.js Dynamic Routes and getServersSideProps occur error while export

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Actually I am new in Next.js and face such error that I never face before!
I am doing my next project where I use getServerSideProps to fetch data. And it was a dynamic route ([id].js)
The problem occur when I hit the build command to deploy the tiny project on my hosting.

This is my next [id].js file –

```
import React from 'react'
import Related from './related';

export default function id(props) {
  return (
    <div>
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-title">{props.data.title}</div>
        <div className="card-body">{props.data.body}</div>
    </div>
    <Related sendData={props.allData}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps =async (ctx)=>{
    const {params} = ctx;
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.id}`)
    const data = await res.json()

    const allRes = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
    const allData = await allRes.json();
    return{
        props:{
         data, allData
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error –

> Build error occurred Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /blog/related
> at C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:395:19
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
> at async C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1094:21
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
> at async C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:971:17
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
> at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\Hridoy\Desktop\demo blog\newapp\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:64:29)

If you want to see the full code on github, this is here – [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/NoorBhuiyan/dynamic_route_error)

And Brother, can you help me by suggesting a better process for data fetching !

Comment: You should try to lint your files. `npx eslint ./**/*.js`. 
My guess is that your missing some semicolons or spaces.
For instance `const data = await res.json()` <- missing semicolon.

Comment: thank you, Brother. But still, this is not working. I put semicolon, and i guess semicolon is not mandatory for JS. Beside that i hit the Eslit command. 

Still not working. :-( 

Can you suggest me anything brother?

Comment: Build error occurred -> you need to fix your files. Take a look at `eslint` to help you doing that.

Comment: You can't use `getServerSideProps` when exporting the app with `next export`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features.

Comment: so how i can deploy this project on hosting? Can you suggest me something brother?